# SQL data check and logic

Tags: sql, conditional-statements

I'm getting a little confused atm, I'm working on a real estate website that requires a small search, the problem is that some listings have a price range, eg from $10,000 to $25,000, others just have a fixed price.

So my database looks like this:

```
id | price | minPrice | maxPrice
1  |       | 10000    | 45000
2  | 7500  |          |
3  |       | 15000    | 20000
4  | 80000 |          |
```

The search consists out of 2 fields: minPriceRange and maxPriceRange, for example, when a users searches for a listing in a price range: minPriceRange = 8000 and maxPriceRange = 17000, then listing 1, 2 and 3 should show up.

I'm a little confused on how to handle this in an SQL statement.

So it would have to check if the price is in between the min and maxPrice, but also take into account that the price can be set seperatly

EDIT

I understand this might be a little confusing.

So basically when I search for a listing between 12000 and 60000, listing 1 and 3 should show up.

That why I can't just do minPrice >= 5000 AND maxPrice <= 60000.

Comment: for 2 price is 7500 why will that show up for - `when I search for a listing between 12000 and 60000`

Comment: @rs. sorry, I'm getting so confused, it should show listing 1 and 3 for that one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DECLARE @table table (id int, price int, minPrice int, maxPrice int)
INSERT into @table 
SELECT 1, null, 10000, 450000 UNION
SELECT 2,7500,null,null UNION
SELECT 3,null,15000  ,20000 UNION
SELECT 4,80000, null,null  

DECLARE @pricemin int = 15000
DECLARE @pricemax int = 90000

SELECT * FROM @table
WHERE (((minPrice IS NOT NULL AND minPrice <= @pricemin)
   AND (maxPRICE IS NOT NULL AND maxPrice >= @pricemax))
   OR
   (price IS NOT NULL AND (( price >= @pricemin) AND (price <= @pricemax))))
```

Comment: Well again, in some cases this will give problems, see my question edit

Comment: I'm gonna mark this as the answer since it helped me solve my problem, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

```
Select id from tablename where (minPrice >= 8000 and maxPrice <=17000) or (price between 8000 and 17000)
```

Comment: Should this work in SQL Server if one of the fields you are comparing is null?

Comment: what if those three fields were nullable?

Comment: @DavidStratton would three paired logic DBMS return those comparisons with unknown results in where phase?

Comment: What confuses me about this is when the price range is between 8000 and 50000, it won't select any listings, eventhough it should select 1, 2 and 3

Comment: @woutr_be what server are you using? can you show your current query?

Comment: Currently I didn't use a query, I just used a if/else to select it now, but it should be done with a query: if(($f['minPrice'] >= $priceRangeMin && $f['minPrice'] <= $priceRangeMax) || ($f['maxPrice'] >= $priceRangeMin && $f['maxPrice'] <= $priceRangeMax))

Comment: @woutr_be why do you think it should select `2` for range `8000` and `50000`?

Comment: @rs. sorry, not 2, it was just an example

Comment: @AllanChua `True or Unknown` yield true` : `select case when 1 = null or 2 = 2 
            then 'True' 
            else case when NOT (1 = null or 2 = 2) 
                 then 'False' 
                 else 'Unknown' 
             end 
        end
` as [seen at documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191504%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović Always keep in mind that T-SQL uses three-valued predicate logic, where logical expressions can evaluate to TRUE, FALSE, or UNKNOWN. With three-valued logic, saying "returns TRUE" is not the same as saying "does not return FALSE." The WHERE phase returns rows for which the logical expression evaluates to TRUE, and doesn't return rows for which the logical expression evaluates to FALSE or UNKNOWN.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović this statement "select case when 1 = null or 2 = 2 then 'True'" yields to true because of the OR operator not because it was NULL :)

Comment: @AllanChua I don't understand. Following query returns a row even though it evaluates ` null = 1 `. By what you are saying it should not do that: `select * 
from (select null c1, 1 c2) a
where c1 = 1 or c2 = 1`. This is the base of queries other people posted.

Comment: @AllanChua Exactly. It is the ` OR `. OP had OR in where clause.

Comment: @AllanChua Sorry for the formatting, emphesises should have been on code. I did not know that I should not put space after tick.

Comment: @NikolaMarkovinović posting in the internet is not that quite reliable :).. books from microsoft press do so because they had been written by the real masters who created the SQL Server not those who were just pretending to know the topic :) see Microsoft SQL Server 2008 TSQL Fundamentals Chapter 2 -Elements of SElect statement WHERE Clause.

Comment: @AllanChua Please don't patronize me. OP uses OR, Unknown or true is true. Torrent of words does not change that.

Comment: this will not work if min price is specified and max price is null or max price is specified and min price is null

Answer (score 2):

It might be better for you to change your design to eliminate the price column, and for those homes with a set price, set the min price and the max price to the same price.

```
id | minPrice | maxPrice
1  | 10000    | 45000
2  | 7500     | 7500
3  | 15000    | 20000
4  | 80000    | 80000
```

This may not be the case depending on other needs, but a solid DB design is critical.  Most apps that I've had to rewrite have been done because some previous programmer (often that previous probgrammer is me) didn't think through the DB design thoroughly and we got backed into a corner based on a flawed design.

**That said, with the current DB design, you can use parentheses to group your where clause**
(Credit where credit is due, 99% of this query was from rs.  I had to modify one item to get it to work.)

```
DECLARE @pricemin int = 8000 
DECLARE @pricemax int = 17000 
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE (ISNULL(minPrice,0) <= @pricemin  
AND    @pricemax <= ISNULL(maxPrice,2147483647))   -- 2147483647 is max Int Value in SQL Server - adjust as necessary
or ISNULL(price,0) between @pricemin and @pricemax
```

Comment: Well this is the same problem, if I use 8000 to 80000, it won't select any listings, even though 1, 2 and 3 should be selected.

Comment: Is it possible that my server doesn't support this? Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL'

Comment: Could be.  Which RDBMS?  I tested mine against SQL Server.  (Took the time to set up the table, insert the data, and run the query after answering wrong the first two times.)

Comment: Just looking at all the confusion, bad SQL queries, and complexity of all the answers we've all posted (including all of my feeble attemtps)  I still stand by my initial suggestion of changing the DB design. Simpler is *almost always* better.

Comment: @DavidStratton thanks for pointing out maxprice  bug in my query. I modified code to a different version and +1 for DB design suggestion and i agree with that

Comment: @rs.  No problem.  I already upvoted you before you fixed it, because it was on the right track!

Comment: I agree on changing the database, but sadly it's not possible anymore, that's why I'm looking for the query, what I could do though is ask the client to just fill in every field, would that help?

Comment: @woutr_be - DavidStratton query and my query are they not working for you? Can you please add exact results you are expecting in your question

Comment: @rs. I'm still getting Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'ISNULL', let me update my question

Comment: post your query that you are running and i think you are using MySQL and not Microsoft SQL Server

Answer (score 2):

This should work:[updated]

```
DECLARE @table table (id int, price int, minPrice int, maxPrice int)
INSERT into @table 
SELECT 1, null, 10000, 450000 UNION
SELECT 2,7500,null,null UNION
SELECT 3,null,15000  ,20000 UNION
SELECT 4,80000, null,null    

DECLARE @pricemin int = 8000
DECLARE @pricemax int = 17000
SELECT * FROM @table WHERE (minPrice <= @pricemin or minPrice is null) 
AND    (@pricemax <= maxPrice or maxPrice is null) 
or ISNULL(price,0) between @pricemin and @pricemax
```

Comment: Hmmm, but won't this have the same problem as mentioned before?
So let's say if I search for anything between 5000 and 8000, it will only select listing 2

Comment: what do you expect it to return for 5000 and 8000? Can you be clear on your end results

Answer (score 0):

How about selecting based on the price range and then using a union to add the results from the fixed price?

A pseude code attempt for a customer looking for prices between 10,000 and 20,000

```
SELECT id FROM table WHERE price BETWEEN 10,000 AND 20,000
UNION
SELECT id FROM table WHERE minPrice > 10,000 AND maxprice < 20,000
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table
WHERE
    price BETWEEN :min AND :max
OR (
    minPrice <= :min AND maxPrice >= :min
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll just post it as a new answer to make it less confusing, after breaking my head some more I finally came up with this one:

```
(((minPrice IS NOT NULL AND minPrice >= 10000) AND (minPrice IS NOT NULL AND minPrice <= 15000)) 
OR 
((maxPrice IS NOT NULL AND maxPrice >= 10000) AND (maxPrice IS NOT NULL AND maxPrice <= 15000))) 
OR
(price IS NOT NULL AND (( price >= 10000) AND (price <= 15000)))
```

Now this work in cases where you select an minimum and maximum price, but if the minimum price is 0, it just selects every possible result

Answer (score 0):

I would write this query as:

```
select *
from t
where <usermin> >= coalesce(minprice, price) and
      <usermax> <= coalesce(maxprice, price)
```

This keeps the logic in one place, by just replacing the min and max with the price when the former are not available.